# autocomplete jquery event to fire another autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have 1 autocomplete events, one searches for code and other searches for description.

For the one that searches for code, after the right code is selected, I would like the description one filled. How can I do that ? Both sources are database driven

here is the code for description search

```
$("#<%=desc2.ClientID%>").autocomplete({
    source: ds2, minLength: 5,
    change: function (event, ui) {
        if (!ui.item) {
            $(this).val('');
                }
            }
        }
        );
```

and here is for code search

```
$("#<%=code1.ClientID%>").autocomplete({
    source: ds, minLength: 3,
        change: function (event, ui) {
            if (!ui.item) {
                $(this).val('');
             }
            //new code start
            else {
                if ($(this).val() === 'Z08') {
                    $("#<%=desc2.ClientID%>").val(Test);
                        } else {
                            $("#<%=hosp_dis1_desc.ClientID%>").val('');
                        }
                    }
                // new code end
                }
            }
            );
```

how can I change this portion in code search

```
if ($(this).val() === 'Z08') {
        $("#<%=desc2.ClientID%>").val(Test);
            } else {
            $("#<%=hosp_dis1_desc.ClientID%>").val('');
    }
```

to display in desc2 by code search??

Comment: you need to give us some code to work with... on the other hand, if your "searches for code" is working, all you need is to trigger the search when "right code is selected", so you could add the search action in the code selection... but that is from the top of my head and without seeing any of your code.

Comment: added code above